# Mercurial commit fails: "The system cannot find the file specified", but it is not really specified

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-commit

I can't commit a single file by Mercurial. Here are different variants of the command:

The variant with --traceback

```
C:\Users\543829657\workspace\dev.appl.ib.cbl>hg commit --traceback "--message=Ad
ded a task Xml2Java for creation request/response files" --user "Petr Gangnus <petr.gangnus@moneta.cz>" -- application/build.gradle
transaction abort!
rollback completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 160, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 885, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 646, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 168, in closure
  File "hgext\color.pyo", line 521, in colorcmd
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 976, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 947, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 882, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 716, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1546, in commit
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyo", line 2456, in commit
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1540, in commitfunc
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 64, in wrapper
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 1508, in commit
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 64, in wrapper
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 1596, in commitctx
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 168, in closure
  File "c:/Users/543829657/workspace/mercurial-tools/commitsigs.py", line 357, in add
  File "c:/Users/543829657/workspace/mercurial-tools/commitsigs.py", line 168, in opensslsign
  File "subprocess.pyo", line 710, in __init__
  File "subprocess.pyo", line 958, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
abort: The system cannot find the file specified
```

The variant with --debug

```
C:\Users\543829657\workspace\dev.appl.ib.cbl>hg commit --debug "--message=
Added a task Xml2Java for creation request/response files" --user "Petr Gangnus <petr.gangnus@moneta.cz>"
 -- application/build.gradle
calling hook precommit.checkfiles: hghook_precommit_checkfiles.fixup_hook
checkfiles: removing tabs and/or trailing whitespace in changed files...
checkfiles: opts:
checkfiles: checked extensions:
checkfiles: ignored extensions: .sln .suo .vcproj .csproj .ui
checkfiles: ignored files:
checkfiles: check diffs only: False
checkfiles: use spaces: True
checkfiles: tab size: 4
checkfiles: considering files:
  application/build.gradle
checkfiles: application/build.gradle ok
committing files:
application/build.gradle
committing manifest
committing changelog
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: The system cannot find the file specified
```

My colleagues and me had cleaned the project committed, re-cloned it, pulled changes or not, checked all python scripts and ssh keys for reachability... It should be OK, but it is not.

I have a suspision that while the error in the "--debug" variant appears after committing changelog, it could be something with it? I don't see any file that is named "changelog" in the project and there are three containing that word and they all are obviously old - cloned from repository.

**About duplication of questions.** It seems that that or similar message pops up in very many absolutely different situations:

[Mercurial Editor: "abort: The system cannot find the file specified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454381/mercurial-editor-abort-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) - The commit fails in this very place of the same script, but... The stack itself is different, and there fails only the commit without the message. **I have the message**. And the author tries to use an alternative default editor and cannot - that is his problem, absolutely different from mine. **I haven't changed the editor**. I have not troubles with editor. I have installed hg, cloned project, changed one file and want to commit it - that is all.

[TortoiseHg can't commit--"The system cannot find the file specified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172303/tortoisehg-cant-commit-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) - here the error message header is not "abort:", but "abort: Adding: "

[android studio gradle refresh failed (The system cannot find the file specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038549/android-studio-gradle-refresh-failed-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) - here the commit is called from Android Studio and the file IS specified

["abort: The system cannot find the file specified" in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014940/abort-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-in-mercurial) - the messages are almost the same, only the missing file IS specified by Mercurial. And the stack is different. And in my case I can update, whereas that author could not.

In others cases on SO with that error message it is not Mercurial what invokes the error.

I have looked at many similar cases on different sites, and I had not found the same problem. Always something important was different.

@Leon has supposed an interesting version below - that the reason is incorrectly set openssl/gnupg. I have checked installation of openssl, ran hg `help commitsigs` - and reading the ouput, noticed such interesting property as `forcesign`.

```
If the parametr is specified with a value of 1, the commit process will be
aborted and rolled back if the changeset cannot be signed for whatever reason
(bad setup, expired certificate and so on. The default is that the commit
will still be successful, but not signed.
```

Yes, it looks promising. ...But even setting that property to 0 changed nothing in the situation.

Comment: Nope. I see the same problem when launching the commit from TortoiseHg or IntelliJ, and they both manage path delimiters OK.... I hoped you have found it and tried - no difference. Thank you anyway

Comment: Is the problem with just that file, or you cannot commit at all?

Comment: The problem could not be with the file to be committed, for notice, it is checked before commiting - and found OK.

Comment: Looks like the problem is due to the [Commitsigs Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommitsigsExtension) - either it is misconfigured or you don't have a X509 certificate for signing your commits.

Comment: @Leon of course, it IS connected with commitsigs, the elder lines of stack shows at that file. Good idea. And there is some list of files, and in the comment to the file some "files" are mentioned as certificate ones. But how these keys worked on cloning/updating and did not work on committing? It seems strange to me...

Comment: As far as I understand Commitsigs is only used during committing, not while cloning/updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `commitsigs.py` entries in your stack trace suggest that the problem is due to the [Commitsigs Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommitsigsExtension). Check that

- you have `gnupg` or `openssl` installed on your system
- you have a valid GPG key (in case of `gnupg`) or a X509 certificate (in case of `openssl`)
- and Commitsigs is properly configured (run `hg help commitsigs` for details). In particular, the path to `gnupg` or `openssl` must be correctly specified, otherwise you may run into the described problem even when `commitsigs.forcesign` mode is disabled.

Comment: Thank you, I'll surely check your way tomorrow.

Comment: I have added the results of checking of your version to the end of the question. It seems, it is something different. :-(

Comment: So what was wrong with your Commitsigs setup/config?

Comment: You have definitely thought in the right direction! For I checked ther reference to 'openssl.path' in the Mercurial.ini - and it was bad! (It contained Program Files in path, but it shouldn't. Please, add to your answer bad or lacking reference to openssl.